# Using command line argument as a file name in perl

Tags: perl, file, bioperl

The following perl script takes an argument from the command line and use that as the output file name.

```
my $str = $ARGV[0];
my $out_handler= Bio::SeqIO->new(
    -file => $str,
    -format => 'Fasta'
);
```

It is similar to this [example](https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-presentation/blob/master/API/Core/exercises/3c.pl). while I run `perl test.pl polg`, I get this error

```
------------- EXCEPTION -------------
MSG: Could not read file 'polg': No such file or directory
STACK Bio::Root::IO::_initialize_io /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Bio/Root/IO.pm:268
STACK Bio::SeqIO::_initialize /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Bio/SeqIO.pm:513
STACK Bio::SeqIO::fasta::_initialize /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Bio/SeqIO/fasta.pm:87
STACK Bio::SeqIO::new /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Bio/SeqIO.pm:389
STACK Bio::SeqIO::new /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/Bio/SeqIO.pm:435
STACK toplevel test.pl:16
-------------------------------------
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: There is no such file. It is a file name that has to be created. I later use `$out_handler->write_seq($mystring);` to write some text into the file (polg). Look at the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is trying to *read* from that file and failing because it doesn't exist

Your example code on github has this

```
-file => '>chrom20.fasta'
```

so I suggest you should try

```
-file => ">$str"
```

or you can run your program as

```
perl test.pl >polg
```

Also, I'm sure you can think of a better name than `$str` for a scalar variable containing an output file name. `$str` is only fractionally better than `$var`